# How can I fix dark textures? - Godot 3.5.1 Mono

Tags: textures, godot

So, I'm making a game in **Godot 3.5.1 Mono** and I'm using a `Texture` in a 3D space (`Spatial`) while I'm using it as a `Control` Element and it is showing up as dark in the editor and in-game. Here is what it looks like in the [Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD7LN.png), [3D space (Spatial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hglLS.png), and the [GUI (Control)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syFq6.png) Here is the window of the [scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Wia.png) and the [import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxnHV.png)

I want a normal texture like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72fhJ.png) - not dark

Comment: Without the entire scene tree it is difficult to judge what causes this, additionally the import settings for the texture might also be relevant.

Comment: Just to make sure is the shaded option in the sprite 3d disabled?

Comment: Yes, shaded is disabled

Comment: Honestly I could take a lot of guesses but I'm not sure what's going on here. Maybe over on their [Q&A](https://godotengine.org/qa/) forum someone knows what causes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have two copies of the `Texture`.

You probably can make it look correct in 2D by changing "HDR mode" to "Force RGBE" when the compress mode is "Video RAM". However fixing the 2D look might ruin the 3D look (this appears to be related to whether or not the png was saved with multiplied alpha - I don't know for sure, and I don't mean the import setting - so your mileage may vary).

If you cannot find import settings that works for both 2D and 3D, I suggest to have two copies of the image file, one for 2D and one for 3D. So they can both have correct import settings for the context in which they are used. In fact, I would default to that in the future.

Comment: I didn't want to make 2 copies because its an addon called "Controller Icons" but this seems to be the only way. Thanks!